# How do I add an ip address to MySQL INSERT INTO database code?

Tags: php, mysql, database

How do I add the $ip address form field to this database code?

```
$form_vars = array('one','two','three');

$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");    

$query = "INSERT INTO recommended SET ";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($form_vars); $i++) {
 $query .= $form_vars[$i].'="'.AddSlashes($_REQUEST[$form_vars[$i]]).'",';              
}

$query .= 'DateTime="'.date('y/m/d g:i a').'"';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error in query: $sql. ".mysql_error());
```

The get $IP line is there but I can't get it to work in the Insert.

I've just reused this code over time but it seems there are 3 assignments to $query.  Is there a simpler way to write this since it's used all the time?

Thanks!

Comment: The preferred method for escaping values for mysql queries is `mysql_real_escape_string()`, not `addslashes()`.  That being said, you don't actually need to escape the IP address if you're getting it from the server.

Comment: you should look into prepared statements...

Comment: you can also look into `inet_atoa`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never add it in the array :

```
$form_vars = array('one','two','three');
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");    

$query = "INSERT INTO recommended SET ";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($form_vars); $i++) {
 $query .= $form_vars[$i]."='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST[$form_vars[$i]])."',";              
}
$query .= "my_ip_column = '". $ip . "',";
$query .= "DateTime='".date('y/m/d g:i a')."'";
```

Notice I switched double quotes and single quotes : in SQL, strings are surrounded by simple quotes.

Instead of escaping all users input, you can use prepared statements. Have a look at [this document](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). You can also read all the documentation about mysqli. `mysql_` functions are now deprecated.

Comment: This is an old piece of code that works so it gets recycled.  I've updated the single and double quotes change.  I'll have a look at prepared statements to update it. Thanks!